# Odoo 10.0 change POS Logo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view, odoo-website

I'm already able to to change the General Odoo logo by activating the Developer Mode. And Click on the logo it self and "Edit Company Data", choose the logo.

But this is not work on POS. The logo's still the default Odoo Logo. How to change it ?

How to do  change the logo for POS / Point of Sales ?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's better to create a module for it rather than editing the core code.

**Create a module eg : test_pos**

> Add below code in
>
> **test_pos/__openerp__.py**

```
{
    'name': 'Company POS LOGO',
    'version': '1.0.0',
    'category': 'web',
    'sequence': 3,
    'author': 'LOYAL',
    'depends': ['web','point_of_sale','mail'
    ],
    'data': [
        # 'change_view.xml',
        'templates.xml',

    ],
    'qweb':['static/src/xml/poschange.xml'],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

> Create poschange.xml and below code
>
> in **test_pos/static/src/xml/poschange.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id='template' xmlspace='preserve'>
<t t-extend="Chrome">
    <t t-jquery=".pos-logo" t-operation="replace">
      <img class="pos-logo" src="/test_pos/static/src/img/logo.png" />  
    </t>
  </t>

</templates>
```

> Add the image that you want to replace with pos logo in
>
> **/test_pos/static/src/img/**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> This is the simple solution of this.
>
> just need to replace the logo.png file at the path in **`point_of_sale
>   module.`**

```
**point_of_sale/static/src/img/logo.png**
```

Comment: This is not recommended since it might eventually be overwritten on higher version updating.